# Как изменить директорию файла в Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Решил сделать небольшую программу. И в этой программе создается файл через **with open()**. Но он создаётся в директории запуска кода.
Каким образом мне сохранить файл, например на рабочий стол? (пытался через **os.chdir()** и не получилось)

Comment: `os.chdir()` должно было получиться, какой путь там был? Вообще, вам нужно получить текущий путь до рабочего стола и к нему добавить название файла и получится абсолютный путь до файла, его можно передать в open

Comment: По умолчанию у меня путь: C:\Users\palki\Desktop\Edit
А когда пытаюсь уже после изменения пути запустить прогу, то она просто падает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import os.path

path_desktop = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop')
file_name = os.path.join(path_desktop, '123.txt')
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

---

Должно сработать и через `os.chdir()` (но мне кажется менять активную директорию, только чтобы файл сохранить/открыть не лучшая идея):

```
os.chdir(path_desktop)
with open('123.txt', 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Накосячил немного в коде.

Comment: @Rise, пожалуйста :) Проголосуйте и примите ответ ;)